# mysql Connector in grails

Tags: mysql, grails

I get the following error after adding mysql to my grails project

> There was an error loading the BuildConfig: Bad artifact coordinates :mysql-connectorj:5.1.22.1, expected format is :[:[:]]: (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Comment: That should be `'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'` or any other version (use the gradle format) from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java

Comment: |Running pre-compiled script
|Script 'Update' not found, did you mean:
   1) DbmUpdate
   2) DbmUpdateSql
   3) DbmUpdateCount
   4) DbmUpdateCountSql
   5) DbmValidate

Comment: thnx for  your answered

Comment: it's actually one of the commented out defaults in a new grails 2.4 project

Answer (score 1):

The formatting of the artifact is incorrect. It should be `'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'`, or any of the others from the [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java) (use the gradle format).